# Maven plugin not overriding parameters in pom.xml with command line input arguments

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have a project that is using Freemarker to generate a docs as a .html file from Javadoc comments.

Input parameter is a directory to .java files that contains Javadoc comments.
Output parameter (optional) is a path where the .html file will be generated.

Next I used maven-plugin-api to create a plugin from it.
I have this Mojo class with @Parameter annotations:

```
package com.direcory.javadoc.template;

import org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.LifecyclePhase;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Mojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Parameter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;

@Mojo(name = "javadoc", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.INITIALIZE)
public class MojoJavadocPlugin extends AbstractMojo {

    @Parameter(property = "sourcePath", required = true)
    private String sourcePath;

    @Parameter(property = "outputPath", defaultValue = ".")
    private String outputPath;

    @Override
    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
        String[] args = new String[]{sourcePath, outputPath};
        
        JavadocArguments arguments = new JavadocArguments(args);
        JavadocGenerator generator = new JavadocGenerator(arguments);
        try {
            Path targetFile = generator.generate();
            getLog().info("Javadoc is generated to: " + targetFile.toAbsolutePath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new MojoExecutionException("Source files path: '" + sourcePath
                    + "' failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I want to use the plugin this is how it looks in pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.directory.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>javadoc-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <configuration>
        <!-- sourcePath is path to directory from which we'll load Java files with Javadoc comments -->
        <sourcePath>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/com/core/</sourcePath>
        <!-- optional, outputPath is path where the html file will be generated -->
        <!-- default outputPath is root of a Project -->
        <outputPath>C:/Projects</outputPath>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>javadoc</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When I set parameters in pom.xml inside  tag:
`<sourcePath>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/com/directory/core/</sourcePath>`
`<outputPath>C:/Projects</outputPath>`

And then I will run a Maven plugin in Command-line and also set a parameters here:
`mvn javadoc-generator:javadoc -DsourcePath="C:/Projects/my_project/src/main/java/com/core/" -DoutputPath="C:/Projects/tmp"`

I was expecting command-line parameters will override the ones from pom.xml, but the parameters from pom.xml were actually used, so .html file was generated in Path: "C:/Projects/".

When I delete pom.xml parameters, then the ones from command-line works like a charm.
Do pom.xml config variables has priority over command-line input? If so, why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have in pom:

```xml
<configuration>
  <sourcePath>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/com/core/</sourcePath>
  <outputPath>C:/Projects</outputPath>
</configuration>
```

Maven resolves all needed properties during pom reading and use final values as constant for next processing and plugin configuration.

---

When you don't configure plugin parameters in pom, default values according to your plugin code will be used, so it will be as:

```xml
<configuration>
  <sourcePath>${sourcePath}</sourcePath>
  <outputPath>${outputPath}</outputPath>
</configuration>
```

Default values for properties from plugin code will be used, so for `outputPath` will be `.`.

In this case you can override properties by cli.

---

Now when you want to have default configuration in pom and want to have a possibility to override it by cli, you should use configuration like:

```xml
<properties>
  <mOoutputPath>my pom default value</mOoutputPath>
</properties>

...

<configuration>
  <outputPath>${mOoutputPath}</outputPath>
</configuration>
```

Now you can override property `mOoutputPath` by cli.

You can use the same properties name as in plugin.